# This is the source code for adding the token to the wallet, but the token is not added to the wallet

Tags: solidity, erc-20, balances, msg.sender

ERC20 Token smart contract:

```js
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
    import "./ERC20.sol";
    
    contract Shinobi is ERC20 
    {
        constructor () ERC20 ("Shinobi Inu","SHI", 100000000 * 1e18,18){
            _balances[_msgSender()] += 100000000*1e18;
        }
    }
    
    mapping (address => uint256) _balances;
    
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
            return msg.sender;
        }
```

Comment: The tokens are added to the `msg.sender` address. Whoever deployed this contract has all the tokens assigned to his address.

Comment: This is exactly the problem, I think the code is correct, but it is not displayed in the wallet, and in testnet, the Holder address is empty and without a holder.

Comment: The sender wallet is not showing the tokens? Are you using Metamask or a wallet like that to try to see the tokens? Tokens are not displayed in the Metamask wallet or something like that by default, because the wallets don't know that your address is being used in a smart contract. Only that smart contract has the information that your address has those tokens. If it's a well known token, you could import it (let your wallet know that there is an ERC20 token smart contract holding your assets and it should call the `balanceOf` function to know how many tokens you have).

Comment: So, I want to know if you are referring to the inability to see the tokens of your address while calling the `balanceOf` method of your `Shinobi` ERC20 contract, or if you are referring to the inability to see the tokens displayed in your wallet (like Metamask). This information will allow me to debug your issue better.

Comment: Inability to see tokens in my address while calling the balanceOf method
In fact, it seems that the order to transfer the token to my wallet address does not work.